# Updated icon for PWA doesn't show if it was installed, via chrome desktop/android or osx/ios, prior to the update

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

I'm not sure if this makes sense so I'll make a step-by-step of what happened:

1. User **installs** PWA on mobile or desktop (chrome/safari). The user sees `icon-v1`
2. I push an update, replacing `icon-v1` with `icon-v2` and some copy updates. Manifest updates and shows the new app icons (Yay!)
3. User re-opens **installed** pwa
4. Copy updates are shown but the icon remains the same

I know with mobile apps you need to update to get the latest, but for PWAs is this also the case?

Has anyone gotten this flow to work without having the user uninstall & reinstall the PWA?

Comment: Apparently icons will not update automatically.

Comment: @Ramtin Is this somewhere in the docs? I just need to know if there's a limitation on this so I can inform the user that a reinstall is required

Comment: each browser/platform are free to decide how their update heuristics are run. There is no immediate update for this right now AFAIK. Give it a few days and it will update.
I have clients complain about this all the time.

Comment: @PeterB I can't find it right now but I read somewhere that the icon of the installed PWA does not change. Maybe the fact that I cannot find it right now means that I might be wrong.

Comment: This site https://web.dev/manifest-updates/ implies chrome updates the icon.  However, i have not gotten that to happen.